# Validator throwing must not be null on optional field

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-validator, customvalidator

I am out of ideas as to why the following conditional validation always throws a 'department must not be null' exception even though the overwritten isValid method allows it. Other Javax validators on optional fields such as pattern and size work fine.

Grateful for any suggestions!

patchRequestClass:

```
public Optional<
  @EnumValidator(enumClass = DepartmentType.class)
  String
  > department;

public EmployeePatchRequest(..., String department) {
        ....,
        this.department = Optional.ofNullable(department);
    }
```

EnumValidator

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = EnumValidatorConstraint.class)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE})
@NotNull
public @interface EnumValidator {

    Class<? extends Enum<?>> enumClass();
    String message() default "must be any of enum {enumClass}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

EnumValidatorConstraint

```
public class EnumValidatorConstraint implements ConstraintValidator<EnumValidator, CharSequence> {
    private List<String> acceptedValues;

    @Override
    public void initialize(EnumValidator annotation) {
        acceptedValues = DepartmentType.getEnumOptions();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(CharSequence value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        if (value == null) {

            return true;
        }

        return acceptedValues.contains(value.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `@NotNull` annotation on `EnumValidator`. That makes it a composed constraint and the `@NotNull` is enforced.

Just drop it and it will work as you expect.